# java UI application - spreate UI from logic and correct handling of threads

Tags: java, swt, threadpool

I'm designing a UI application that also involves using database. I understand that I should separate the database-logic-UI layers from each other.
 but I dont understand from which layer should I call the main function, and from which layer I should handle a thread pool.

What I tried to do until now is to put the main function and the thread pool in the logic package (in a class that is called mainAppClass), and from there to start an instance of the UI class (not on different thread). 
When the UI layer would like to open a new thread, It will use the thread pool from the mainAppClass.

when I try this Im getting org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
I understand (from previous stack over flow questions) that I'm getting this error because UI thread can be run only from the "main UI thread".
but what is this main UI thread in my application?

Basically my questions are:

where should I put the main function ? (whick package UI or logic) 
if in the logic package, so should I instance the UI in a different thread?

should I use different thread pools for the UI and the logic layers?

also a link to a short exemple of application that involve all three different layers will be great.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main class should be in the UI package.

I don't know SWT, but generally you have single GUI thread and from the sounds of it your trying to run UI code on a separate thread (hence the exception). Essentially you shouldn't have a thread pool for running UI code (or at least I can't think of good reason why you would want one).

However, you haven't posted any details on what your trying to accomplish either so it's hard to know what to recommend. But generally you would use the thread pool to avoid locking up the UI thread (so it will exist in the UI package).

For threading details I'd check out the following. It's got an example of threading in relation to Swing which might help you better understand the relation between threads and the GUI.

https://www.udemy.com/java-multithreading/

You could also think about checking out the following book. It focused on testing, however it has an example GUI application that provides a good example of separation of concerns (unfortunately it also uses Swing). At the very least, the example code is available at the website to check out.

http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/

By 'database-logic-ui' I'm assuming your roughly referencing to a 3-layer architecture. The best way to think of the relation between the first two layers and the UI is what would be required to replace the UI with a web-based or console based interface?

As a really rough rule of thumb, whatever code does not change, for each different method of presentation (db code, business logic, etc.), should reside in the first-two layers. Since the main method will differ for each type of presentation layer it should reside in the UI package.

Also it seems like your confusing logical and physical design. The book Java Application Architecture: Modularity Patterns with Examples Using OSGi does a great job of outlining the difference and would make it clearer where different parts of the code should reside.

Sorry I can't help more, but hopefully it's enough to get you started. Good luck!